# How to Achieve Consistent Design Sizing in Flutter Without External Packages or Design Frame-based Calculations?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design

I'm trying to design a screen in Flutter using a Figma prototype. I have used all the values as defined in Figma, including padding, height, width, letter spacing, and line height, but the end result does not look the same as in Figma.

What are the ways to achieve a design similar to Figma's in terms of sizing so it does not look too big or small in Flutter without using any packages or Figma frame-based calculations?

[Design in flutter](https://imgur.com/C7q8Ro0)

[Figma Design](https://imgur.com/pEsF7wM)

Comment: Of course the size will vary between devices. You should not worry about that. See: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/

Comment: The article you shared is useful when we don't have to work with specific height and width, and the height and width will be based on children elements. But in the above design, as it's a login, at least we should have proper sizing so that all the content fits on the screen.